# lstlisting: mathescape and Erlang

Tags: math-mode, listings

I am trying to combine to use `mathescape` together with the Erlang syntax highlighting in the package `lstlisting`, as described in Section 4.14 of its manual:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=Erlang,
    mathescape=true
}

\begin{document}
\lstinline{$n_1$.lookup(k)}
\end{document}
```

This fails with:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> \egroup 

l.10 \lstinline{$n_1$.lookup(k)}
```

The code works fine for other languages, e.g. C. Does the style for Erlang miss something to allow this?

Comment: `\lstinline|$n_1$.lookup(k)|` seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it works. You might want to put that up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listings` package allows the syntax

```
\lstinline{...}
```

but marks it as “experimental”, see p. 26 of the manual, section 4.2. Section 5.1 talks about using `\lstinline` in the argument of another command; the end of section 5.1 tells, however, that this is not safe.

In particular, `mathescape` turns out not be compatible with the experimental syntax, so you should use something like

```
\lstinline|$n_1$.lookup(k)|
```

(use, as a delimiter, a character that doesn't appear in the string to be typeset, just like for the `\verb` command).